# How to capture the rotated image to stream?

Tags: uwp, image-rotation, rendertargetbitmap

I am using the UWP image control.

I have rotated the image to 45 degrees by applying the Rotate transform(Angle = 45) now I want to convert the rendered rotated image to stream. So I have tried the RenderTargetBitmap to capture the image but it is not worked. It returns an actual image instead of a rotated image. Please provide any suggestions on this.

```
        var rendererShapeViewBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream renderedStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await rendererShapeViewBitmap.RenderAsync(editorImage);
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, renderedStream);
        IBuffer pixelBuffer = await rendererShapeViewBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
           (uint)rendererShapeViewBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)rendererShapeViewBitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, pixelBuffer.ToArray());
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        renderedStream.Seek(0);
```

Before getting stream:
[image]

After getting the stream

[image]

My requirement:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could let the `Image` control within a panel such as `StackPanel` or `Grid`, and convert the panel which includes your rotated image to stream by using [RenderTargetBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap?view=winrt-19041) class.

**Update:**

The size of `Grid` will adapt to the size of the `Image` control and the size of `Grid` is always bigger than the size of the `Image` control if the image is rotated.

You could check the following code as a sample.

```
<Grid x:Name="panel">
    <Image Source="Assets/YourImage.png"  Width="300" Height="300"
       x:Name="image" Margin="10">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="45" CenterX="150" CenterY="150"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var renderShapeViewBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream renderedStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await renderShapeViewBitmap.RenderAsync(panel);
    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, renderedStream);
    IBuffer pixelBuffer = await renderShapeViewBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
        (uint)renderShapeViewBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)renderShapeViewBitmap.PixelHeight,
            96, 96, pixelBuffer.ToArray());
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    renderedStream.Seek(0);
}
```

**Update:**

The image stream captured by `RenderTargetBitmap` with an `Image` control does not include the rotation information. Therefore, you cannot get the rotated image stream only.

You could check the following code as a workaround:

```
    <Grid x:Name="panel" Background="Green" >
        <Image Source="Assets/2211.png"   Width="300" 
           x:Name="image" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45" CenterX="0" CenterY="0"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var width = panel.Width;
        var height = panel.Height;
         
//We can calculate the grid’size based on the size of image. Change the size of grid to wrap the image, then capture the grid which just surrounds the image
        panel.Height = image.ActualWidth / Math.Sqrt(2) + image.ActualHeight / Math.Sqrt(2);
        panel.Width = image.ActualWidth / Math.Sqrt(2) + image.ActualHeight / Math.Sqrt(2); 
        var renderShapeViewBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream renderedStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await renderShapeViewBitmap.RenderAsync(panel);
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, renderedStream);
        IBuffer pixelBuffer = await renderShapeViewBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
            (uint)renderShapeViewBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)renderShapeViewBitmap.PixelHeight,
            96, 96, pixelBuffer.ToArray());
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        renderedStream.Seek(0);
       ……
        //panel.Width = width;  //If you want the panel to remain the original size, you can use the two line code.
        //panel.Height = height;
    }
```

Note, you need to [rotate your image around its center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.rotatetransform?view=winrt-19041#remarks) with `CenterX` and `CenterY` as **0** and `UIElement.RenderTransformOriginal` as **(0.5,0.5)** for simple calculation.

Comment: How to add the image inside the grid? Image size and grid size are different.

Comment: I update the answer and maybe you could check the update to see if it solves your question.

Comment: Thanks.. It is meet my requirement partially.  How to get the rotated image stream only currently I get the panel stream?  I have added the images.

Comment: I update the answer and maybe you could check the update to see if it meets your requirements.